# how to use BehaviorSubject with Observable

Tags: javascript, html, angular, observable

I have a div and need to add attribute depends on store result. The store works as expected, when I click on certain div it's value changed (return `true` or `false`) and in my component I need to get updated value, but as I call it in `ngOnInit` it works only once and not updating. I've read about `BehaviorSubject` but don't understand how to convert my observable to it correctly. Would appreciate any help!

Here's my code

html

```
<div class="details__header" [attr.isOpened]="isOpened ? 'opened' : 'closed'">
```

ts

```
isOpened: boolean;

constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.select(selectSearchResultState).subscribe(el => this.isOpened = el);
}
```

I've tried `async` pipe in html and it works, but I need to use this variable in my code, so this doesn't work for me

Comment: "_when I click on certain div it's value changed_" - why not then place the subscription inside this `div`'s click event handler instead of `ngOnInit` hook?

Comment: div that change this value in store is in other component, so I need to detect store changes and get last value from it

Answer (score 2):

You should define `isOpened` as an Observable like this:

```
isOpened$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isOpened$ = this.store.select(selectSearchResultState);
}
```

Then use it in the template with an async pipe:

```
<div class="details__header" [attr.isOpened]="(isOpened$ | async) ? 'opened' : 'closed'">
```

There's more information about observables in the documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

Comment: Thank's, but I wrote in the end `I've tried async pipe in html and it works, but I need to use this variable in my code, so this doesn't work for me`

Comment: You can use the observable in the code by subscribing to it. 
example:
this.isOpened$.subscribe(isOpened => {
  if (isOpened) { doSomething(); }
});

More information can be found in [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subscription)